# What happens when using concatenation operator {} this way

Tags: verilog

I see this description in 
[link](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~ee577/faq/verilog_faq.html)

I don't get it that what happens when using `{$random()}` to get a positive number?

Q: I want to have a 2-bit random variable. How can I do that?

$random function call returns a 32-bit random number each time it is called. The random number is a signed integer; it can be positive or negative. Therefore, if 2-bit random varialbe is desired, you need a modulo operation as follows.

```
reg [1:0] R;
R = $random % 2;
```

Above example will generate random value between -1 to 1. If only positive is needed, use concatenation operator as follows.

```
reg [1:0] R;
R = {$random} % 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `%2` , you can directly assign a {$random} value to R as it will be inn binary.The rhs value is truncated on the left(MSB) to make space for as many LSB bits as possible.On the other hand if the number of bits on LHS > number of bits in RHS, it is filled with zeros.

Comment: Your answer enlighten me! And %2 is needed because R has 2-bits, will have value ranged 0-3 if don't have %2.

Comment: @awill values 0-3 are what you want for a 2 bit random variable. `%2` will give you a 1 bit random variable, R[1] will always be 0.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to directly address your question about "what happens when using `{$random()}` to get a positive number".

Signedness in Verilog is subtle.  To really grok what's going on here:

- The `$random` system function returns a **signed** integer
- The concatenation operator, `{...}`, produces an **unsigned** result
- The modulus operator, `%`, produces a signed result when its first argument is signed.
  ([IEEE 1364-2005](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1364-2005.html) Section 5.1.5; [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Section 11.4.3)

Because of these rules,

- `$random % 2` is a random, 32-bit signed integer, modulo 2 --> signed result
- `{$random} % 2` is a random, 32-bit unsigned integer, modulo 2 --> unsigned result

So what happens when you assign these expressions to your 2-bit, unsigned register `R`?

In the signed case, there are surprisingly actually **three possible values for R**, because `$random % 2` can actually return any of 0, 1, or -1 (e.g., when `$random` produces -1).  After this intermediate value is sign-extended to 2 bits, the final result for `R` is therefore 0, 1, or 3. (but never 2)

In the unsigned case, everything makes sense and you either get `R` being 0 or 1.